# Mapping string of numbers to ints returning NaN

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, map-function

I have a simple program where it gets users grades and calculates their weighted grades. My function takes a string of grades and returns an array of integers, but keeps returning `Nan`. Here is my function:

```
function getUserScores(subject) {
  var category;
  switch (subject) {

    case "test":
      category = document.getElementById("testGrades").value;
      category = category.split(',').map(function(item) { 
        return parseInt(item, 10);
      });

    case "quiz":
      category = document.getElementById("quizGrades").value;
      category = category.split(',').map(function(item){
        return parseInt(item, 10);
      });

    case "homework":
      category = document.getElementById("homeworkGrades").value;
      category = category.split(',').map(function(item){
        return parseInt(item, 10);
      });

    default:
      return "Error: something went wrong with switch statement";
  }  
}
```

So if I call it with `getUserScores("test")` it'd grab `testGrades` value which is `"96, 92, 94"` and returns `NaN` instead of `[96, 92, 94]`? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You forgot to exit from each `case` by `break`

Comment: I thought `return` was the `break` and you didn't need to include it?

Comment: The `return` inside the `map` fn does not affect the `getUserScores`, I think you need to also add a `return` inside `getUserScores`

Comment: That `return` is only mapping your elements from the string to the int versions, not for breaking out of the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively, just remove the `switch` statement altogether:

```
function getUserScores(subject) {
    var ele = document.getElementById(subject + "Grades");
    if (ele === null) {
        return null;
    }

    var category = ele.value;
    category = category.split(',').map(function(item) { 
        return parseInt(item, 10);
    });

    return category;  
}
```

To ensure that the code wouldn't break when an element didn't exist, I return `null` when `getElementById` can't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a break in each case, and also return category

```
function getUserScores(subject) {
  var category;
  switch (subject) {

    case "test":
      category = document.getElementById("testGrades").value;
      category = category.split(',').map(function(item) { 
        return parseInt(item, 10);
      });
      break;
    case "quiz":
      category = document.getElementById("quizGrades").value;
      category = category.split(',').map(function(item){
        return parseInt(item, 10);
      });
      break;
    case "homework":
      category = document.getElementById("homeworkGrades").value;
      category = category.split(',').map(function(item){
        return parseInt(item, 10);
      });
      break;
    default:
      return "Error: something went wrong with switch statement";
  }
  return category;
}
```

Also, make sure that you are grabbing the value that you need, that the selector is working right with:

```
category = document.getElementById("testGrades").value;
// add a console.log to test it
console.log(category);
```